# Align text next to vertical navigation icon

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the text next to the navigation icon but not sure how to. I've tried the i class but it doesn't work. Not sure how to do it. Can someone show me the best way to accomplish this? I have the icons saved the img folder. Here is my code:

```
<div id="main-sidebar"> <!-- right column -->
    <ul class="side-nav">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="offers"></i>Holiday Offers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="test-drive"></i>Schedule A Test Drive</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="directions"></i>Directions To Mill Valley Inspirent</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="explore"></i>Explore Models</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="quote"></i>Request A Quote</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="request"></i>Request A Trade Appraisal</a></li>               
        <li><a href="#"><i class="finance"></i>Explore Financing Options</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

.offers {
background: url('../img/user.png');
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.test-drive {
background: url('../img/user.png');
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}

etc......
```

[image: image of desired navigation icon and text]

Answer (score 0):

set for a-tag padding-left = 3 icons width
set background for element with padding

```
a.offers {
    background-image: url('../img/user.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 50%; // or 50% 0;
}

a.offers {
    background-image: url('../img/user.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px 50%; // or 50% 10px; // move background left-right or top-bottom
}
```

Comment: Alright, so I sort of figured it out but am not sure if  this is best practice. Also, I would like to have the icon align-centered with text. Right now it sits on top of p element. Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/L1161uaj/